# Update and ASP.NET MVC model on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm trying to update model on button click with no success: every time I push the button an HttpGet controller method is invoked.

Here is my markup

```
@model DataInterface.Model.Entry

<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Survey")'">Finish survey</button>
```

Here is Controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Survey()
{
    var entry = new Entry();
    return View(entry);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Survey(Entry newEntry)
{
       // save newEntry to database
}
```

When I click button HttpGet method is invoked. Why?

---

It is bad to be a rookie)
Thanks to all!

Comment: well, that's the exact thing you tell the browser to do. On button click, the URL of the browser is changed to point to the `Survey` method in your controller. The browser will send a get request to it and process the response. The easiest way to send a `POST` request is by submitting a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access a `URL` without explicitly specifying the `HTTP method`, `ASP.NET MVC` will assume a `GET` request. To change this, you can add a form and send it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Finish survey" />    
}
```

If you do this, your `POST` method will be invoked. The `Entry` parameter, however, will be empty, since you do not specify any values to send along with the request. The easiest way to do so is by specifying input fields, e.g. text inputs, dropdown, checkboxes etc.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
    <input type="submit" value="Finish survey" />    
}
```

If you have the object stored on the server somewhere and only want to finish it off by writing it into the database or changing its status, you could pass the `Id` of the object (or some temporary Id) along the post request and make the controller method work only with the Id:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <input type="submit" value="Finish survey" />    
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Survey(Entry newEntry)
{
    // newEntry.Id will be set here
}
```

Comment: Side note: Since the view was generated by the `Survey()` method, then all that's needed is `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {...` - its only necessary to include the parameters if you want to override the defaults

Answer (score 0):

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "<ControllerName>", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       <input  type="submit" value="Finish survey" />    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must declare your form

```
@model DataInterface.Model.Entry
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "Controlleur", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form", id = "RequestForm" }))
{
<input  type="submit" value="Finish survey" />
}
```